# Is it possible to have material emission & procedural map?

Tags: unity-game-engine

What lighting options are there to give a material a emission glow in a procedural generated map?

From what I can see [StandardShaderMaterialParameterEmission](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StandardShaderMaterialParameterEmission.html) only works for static objects, and procedural maps & static do not mix?

Thanks,
Lewis

Answer (score 0):

The GameObject class has a boolean `isStatic` property.

You could set the GameObject(s) in question to static *after* they have been procedurally generated. To summarise:

1. Procedurally generate an object/map section
2. Set `isStatic` to true for that object/map section

The [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-isStatic.html) don't outline how to set something to static in code so here is the basic idea:

```
GameObject.isStatic = true;
```